# Spinner causing issues with immersive mode

Tags: java, android, spinner

My app is set to be fullscreen and immersive mode so the Status bar and Navigation bar are hidden. I wrote a custom spinner to be able to prevent the navigation bar from appearing when the spinner is clicked. This actually works but the main Activity view still gets resized as if the navigation and status bar has shown. The area where they would normally be displayed is just white. It will stay like this until I click something in the spinner or cancel by clicking outside of the spinner. Is there something I can call on the main view to refresh it's layout to remove the white space or prevent it entirely?

When the Activity is loaded I call my hideSystemUI method:

```
 private void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Custom spinner onClickListener resets the view back to the original UI layout. So I do not see the actual navigation bars or status bars, just the white space they would have occupied.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I have found out why this is happening and will post an answer to my solution for future people since this problem seems to happen and I have not seen many answers to the issue.